# How can I use dart:ui in a command line Dart application?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-packages

I know that `dart:ui` contains "Built-in types and core primitives for a Flutter application". I'd like to use `Color` and other functionality from this package (`computeLuminance`) in a command-line (Dart) application that converts some data files.

(I would also like to use [estimateBrightnessForColor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/estimateBrightnessForColor.html) from Flutter Material, but I guess this is even harder, or impossible.)

I'm using the Dart SDK that is bundled with the Flutter SDK.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:ui';
```

I get `Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'`

As a side note, I can import and use `dart:ui` on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/).

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Created a feature request [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119424).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use color-related functionality such as computeLuminance in a command-line Dart application, you can consider using the color package provided by the Dart ecosystem. This package offers color-related utilities and operations that can be used independently of the Flutter framework.

To use the color package in your command-line Dart application, follow these steps:

Open your project's **pubspec.yaml** file.
Add the color package as a dependency:

```
dependencies:
  color: ^2.1.0
```

Save the file, and run **flutter pub get** or **dart pub get** in the terminal to fetch the package.
In your Dart file, import the color package:

example:

```
import 'package:color/color.dart';

void main() {
  Color color = Color.rgb(128, 128, 128);
  double luminance = color.computeLuminance();
  
  if (luminance > 0.5) {
    print('Color is bright');
  } else {
    print('Color is dark');
  }
}
```

Now you can utilize color-related functionality from the color package, including **computeLuminance**, in your command-line Dart application.

Regarding **estimateBrightnessForColor**, it is tightly integrated with the Flutter Material framework and relies on the Flutter rendering engine. Therefore, it's not feasible to use **estimateBrightnessForColor** in a command-line Dart application.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Several of your answers from the last two days appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues. m

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).